# Is there a RegEx that can satisfy all these conditions?

Tags: java, regex

The user input will only be accepted when,

> - Only upper case letters 'X','O','D','L','E' are present in the user input.
> - Any amount of 'O's only when in between 'D's
> - 'DLE' is at the end and not by itself.
>
> 'X' counts as anything.

So for example the user input: 'DDLE', 'DOODLE', 'XXXDODOOOODLEDLX' - will work.

But these examples will not work ("error, wrong input"): 'DLE','DOOODLLE' 'DLEDOD'

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere? Take it one step at a time. The first criterion would be a good place to start.

Comment: short answer; **yes, most likely, but probably the wrong solution**. Long answer; **Where is your attempt?**

Comment: And... why exactly should we be writing this for you?

Comment: Ah my bad, should have included my attempt too. I was just wondering if RegEx alone can do this job in java or if anything else is needed

Comment: these *"requirements"* are ambiguous at best! what does *X counts as anything* even mean? And as far as I can tell there is no way all three will match given your rules only two of those will match.

Comment: per your criteria `XXXDODOOOODLEDLX` should not match - look at end

Comment: 'X' counts as anything @alphabravo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on criteria and examples provided

<s>`^(?=.+[DX][LX][EX]$)(?!.*[^DO]O+[^DO])[XODLE]+$`</s>

```
^(?=.+[DX][LX][EX]$)(?!.*[^DO]O+)(?!.*O+[^DO])[XODLE]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/315)

---

or depends on your interpretation of "'X' counts as anything" - meaning `DOODDLEX` is valid

    <s>`^(?=.+[DX][LX][EX]X*$)(?!.*[^DO]O+[^DO])[XODLE]+$`</s>

```
^(?=.+[DX][LX][EX]X*$)(?!.*[^DO]O+)(?!.*O+[^DO])[XODLE]+$
```

or as suggested below

```
^(?=.+[DX][LX][EX]X*$)(?!.*[^DOX]O+)(?!.*O+[^DOX])[XODLE]+$
```

Comment: I would interpret the "X counts as anything" statement in a way, that it could also replace the D for surrounding O's - would change `(?!.*[^DO]O+[^DO])` to `(?!.*[^DOX]O+[^DOX])`